# In sculpt mode, stroke:[curve] is not on top of mesh surface

Tags: modeling, sculpting, brushes

its not even editing anything its just going through the mesh entirely. into the 3d abyss.
[image]

i want to do what this guy is doing here in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uideuXvJNX4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an answer from blenderartists.org from [zeauro] :

> "The PaintCurve is relative to screen view. It is not stuck to 3D
> Object.
>
> In first video, he is not changing the point of view, while he is
> creating the curve. In second video, he does not, too, for first two
> strokes. Then, he is panning the view for the third one and you can
> see tat curve is not moving with the 3D object.
>
> They have meshes a lot more dense than yours. Sculpt mode is only
> displacing vertices of mesh. You need to have enough vertices under
> curve to see a result while pressing Enter or Draw Curve button. For
> that, you need to remesh mesh or to use Dyntopo."

-------[image]
me: “problem stems from assuming a tool works similar to tools in the program”

and it does affect mesh regardless of resolution i just need to make my circle/meshes bigger and ive used the differrent default blender meshes shown in the photo to prove it.